# maven-android-plugin No Android API Level has been configured

Tags: android, maven, maven-3, android-maven-plugin

I'm getting this error when trying to build my android project using `maven-android-plugin`:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.7.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project android-input-device: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.7.0:generate-sources failed:  No Android API Level has been configured.  Add e.g. 17 to the plugin configuration. -> [Help 1]

-even though I've set the SDK version in the configuration of the plugin. Here's a snippet from my POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha-11</version>
    <configuration>
        <sdk>
            <platform>11</platform>
        </sdk>
        <emulator>
            <avd>21</avd>
        </emulator>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version - 3.8.0 and report back if you still have issues. This should work but the version you are using is VERY old and I am not surprised if it is not working. Also .. the plugin has been renamed to android-maven-plugin.